# join enumerable to produce string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, enumerable

Ruby arrays have the `#join` method that produces a string by joining the elements of the array, adding an optional separator.

Other enumerables such as ranges don't have the same method.

You could emulate the behaviour using `#inject`, e.g.

```
('a'..'z').inject('') do |acc, s| 
  if acc.empty?
    s
  else
    acc << ' some separator ' << s.to_s  
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to join enumerables? Was `#join` omitted for a particular reason?

**EDIT:**

One thing I would be concerned about would be copying a massive enumerable to an array. Of course that's seldom a use case, but still. For instance:

```
(1 .. 1_000_000_000_000_000).to_a.join
```

Therefore I'm particularly interested in solutions that don't require generating an array with all the values as an intermediate step.

Comment: "Was #join omitted for a particular reason" - some enumerables are infinite. Arrays never are.

Comment: I doubt I understand what is asked in edited part. If you want to join without a converting to the array, you might `inject` as you did.

Comment: JFYI, your proposed replacement with `inject` is broken. But yes, it's a valid approach.

Comment: "Was #join omitted for a particular reason"  -- Was `#join` present at any time?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: @sawa I don't think so. By "omitted" I mean "left out".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev a good point. Enumerables do offer some aggregation methods, though, for instance `#count`. It offers specialised output for infinite cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code within your question is already as optimal as it gets, but it's possible to remove the condition inside your block:

```rb
e = ('a'..'z').to_enum

joined_string = e.reduce { |acc, str| acc << ' some separator ' << str }.to_s
```

Without passing an argument to `#reduce`, the first time the block gets called, `acc` and `str` would represent the first two elements of the enumerable. The additional `.to_s` at the end is to ensure that an empty string is returned if the enumerable is empty.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I had in mind. To work with non-string enums I think you need `joined_string = e.reduce { |acc, str| acc.to_s << ' some separator ' << str.to_s }`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html):

```
('a'..'z').to_a.join(' some separator ')
```

Or (effectively the same):

```
[*'a'..'z'].join(' some separator ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is absolutely a solution. Please see my edit for more detail.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _as in the OP_ which is also somewhat above :)

Answer (score 1):

```
> [*'a'..'z'] * ' some separator '

#=> "a some separator b some separator c some separator d some separator e some separator f some separator g some separator h some separator i some separator j some separator k some separator l some separator m some separator n some separator o some separator p some separator q some separator r some separator s some separator t some separator u some separator v some separator w some separator x some separator y some separator z"
```

Comment: Cool use of `*`. But the semantics are not the same as join because the separator is inserted before `'a'` in the output.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the example in the question now. It's supposed to be `join` semantics.